# how to build gst-rtsp-server on windows?

Tags: meson-build

i got source code form [https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server，](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server%EF%BC%8C)
then i follow https://mesonbuild.com/Getting-meson.html to Installing Meson and Ninja with the MSI installer.
but when i run build it seems like not correct.

```
D:\>cd gst-rtsp-server-master

D:\gst-rtsp-server-master>meson build
The Meson build system
Version: 0.56.0
Source dir: D:\gst-rtsp-server-master
Build dir: D:\gst-rtsp-server-master\build
Build type: native build
Project name: gst-rtsp-server
Project version: 1.19.0.1
C compiler for the host machine: clang (clang 8.0.0 "clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)")
C linker for the host machine: clang link 14.16.27042.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -fvisibility=hidden: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-strict-aliasing: YES
Message: Disabling deprecated GLib API
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wredundant-decls: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Waggregate-return: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Waddress: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-multichar: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdeclaration-after-statement: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wvla: YES
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
Found Pkg-config: NO
Did not find CMake 'cmake'
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency glib-2.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency glib-2.0

meson.build:136:0: ERROR: Neither a subproject directory nor a glib.wrap file was found.

A full log can be found at D:\gst-rtsp-server-master\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
```

i am totaly confused.please help...

Comment: You need to install pkg-config first, here is a good guide https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs#installation-windows and it's suggested https://sourceforge.net/projects/pkgconfiglite/ (I haven't tried)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really trivial on windows. I performed the following steps to pull this off:

- Install visual studio 2019
- Install gstreamer vs2019 edition with developer headers
- Install Ninja-build
- Install meson: `python -m pip install meson`
- Open a x64 visual studio command shell
- Update your path variable in this shell: `set PATH=C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin;%PATH%` (note that `pkg-config` is included in the installation of gstreamer).
- `cd` to your path where you cloned `gst-rtsp-server`
- Run meson setup: `meson setup build`
- Compile the rtsp code `meson compile -C build`
- Run `build\examples\test-readme.exe`
- Connect to the rtsp stream using VLC